# Suitable design pattern for report system

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

In method `main` I have `String page` which contain some big text, and such code:

```
List<String> wordsList = getWordsList(page);
System.out.println("Total number of words is: " + wordsList.size());

Map<String, Long> wordsSortedMap = getWordsSortedMap(wordsList);
wordsSortedMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(v + "\t" + k));
```

As you see I just use util methods `getWordsList` and `getWordsSortedMap` to construct needed data and print it out to console.

I want change program to do it scalable, to be able to add new types of reports without changing the existing code.

For example, the input data is always this `page` variable. And for example in the `main` could be this:

```
ReportsExecutor.printReportOne(page);
ReportsExecutor.printReportTwo(page);
```

or this:

```
ReportOne reportOne = new ReportOne(page);
ReportTwo reportTwo = new ReportTwo(page);
reportOne.execute();
reportTwo.execute();
```

So to add new report type I just implement new method or class, etc.

Is there a suitable design pattern or any OOP best practices for this case?

Comment: TBH, I read your question 3 times and could not understand it.

Comment: What do ya mean by *new types of reports*?

Comment: Now it prints the number of words on the page and the number of repetitions for each word. I want incapsulate this in some "report". And want to be able add any other "reports": print number of letters, number of words which contain digits... any statistical report on this text

Comment: IMO the Builder or the Visitor pattern would suit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my strong opinion is that your question is primarily about OOP i'll make an example in C# (because i'm most proficient in).

The idea is to use a combination of the Builder and Visitor pattern to process reports .

First, i've defined the Report class like the following (very primitive):

```
public interface IReport
{
    void Print();
}

public class Report : IReport
{
    private readonly IList<string> lines;

    public Report()
    {
        lines = new List<string>();
    }

    public void AddLine(string line)
    {
        lines.Add(line);
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        foreach (var l in lines) Console.Out.WriteLine(l);
    }
}
```

Then i've defined the interface for the builder:

```
public interface IReportBuilder
{
    void Execute();
    IReport Product { get; }
}
```

and visitor that suits our needs:

```
public interface IWordVisitor
{
    void VisitWord(string word);
}
```

The implementation of the page word statistics would look like:

```
public class PageStatisticVisitor : IWordVisitor
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, long> stats;

    public PageStatisticVisitor()
    {
        stats = new Dictionary<string, long>();
    }

    public IDictionary<string, long> Stats { get { return stats; } }

    public void VisitWord(string word)
    {
        long currentStat;
        if (stats.TryGetValue(word, out currentStat)) currentStat++;
        else currentStat = 1;
        stats[word] = currentStat;
    }
}
```

(just counts the same words in the text).

I incapsulate the page content into the Page class that does now the visitor:

```
 public class Page
{
    private string pageContent;
    public Page(string content)
    {
        pageContent = content;
    }

    public void Accept(IWordVisitor visitor)
    {
        foreach (var w in pageContent.Split())
        {
            visitor.VisitWord(w);
        }
    }
}
```

The word statistics report builder:

```
public class WordStatisticsBuilder : IReportBuilder
{
    private Report report;
    private Page page;

    public WordStatisticsBuilder(Page page)
    {
        report = new Report();
        this.page = page;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        var psv = new PageStatisticVisitor();
        page.Accept(psv);            
        foreach (var s in psv.Stats)
        {
            report.AddLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", s.Key, s.Value));
        }
    }

    public IReport Product
    {
        get { return report; }
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
var page = new Page(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.");

        var statistics = new WordStatisticsBuilder(page);
        statistics.Execute();

        statistics.Product.Print();
```

I hope you've got an idea and could implement it in JAva.